# Wrong Conversion from datenum

Tags: matlab, datetime

In a Serial receiving process, I have a incoming data

```
pressure ={'2016-04-14'    '14:18:48'    '321'}
datenum(datestr(cellfun(@(x,y) [x y],pressure(1),pressure(2),'un',0)));
```

Here, the result of date time serial from above step,

```
ans = 7.3648e+05`
```

When I convert back, the result is giving a different time into the future:

```
datestr(ans)
ans = 29-May-2016 22:18:48
```

where this working wrong?

Comment: Please make `press` proper MATLAB syntax. Also what is in `press(1)` and `press(2)`?

Comment: tried this - cstime = 10^7*60*60*24*(datenum(datestr(cellfun(@(x,y) [x y],pressure(1),pressure(2),'un',0))) - 367) and it gives the exact same time you got. Strange...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you combine date and hour, you need to make sure that there is a space between the date and the hour. Your `cellfun` call creates the string `'2016-04-1414:18:48'`, which then gets mis-interpreted.

`cellfun(@(x,y) [x ' ' y],pressure(1),pressure(2),'un',0))` fixes the problem. Note that you can drop the first call to `datestr`, and write

```
numericDate = datenum(cellfun(@(x,y) [x ' ' y],pressure(1),pressure(2),'un',0)))
```